# oracle sql - how to get the sum of whole year(12 months) with group by dimension columns

Tags: sql, oracle

`enter code here` Hi all,
 I have a scenario where i need to find the variance comparing 2 tables 
 the first table is Z_F_DDEPL_ALLRPTG and second table is F_DDEPL_ALLRPTG
  both the table shame column names and same number of columns.
 there are columns which has amount's in it ( year's from march to February), so i need to sum those amount columns  and group by the left over dimension columns and  compare both the tables and see if there is any amount difference.
this is the sql i created, but for some reason its not giving me the output i need please help

```
select distinct 
YEAR_CD,
SCENARIO_CD,
MANAGEMENT_CD,
PRODUCT_CD,
OPCO_CD,
ACCOUNT_CD,
sum(BEGBALANCE_QTY) as BEGBALANCE_QTY ,
sum(MAR_QTY) as MAR_QTY,
sum(APR_QTY) as APR_QTY,
sum(MAY_QTY) as MAY_QTY,
sum(JUN_QTY) as JUN_QTY,
sum(JUL_QTY) as JUL_QTY,
sum(AUG_QTY) as AUG_QTY,
sum(SEP_QTY) as SEP_QTY,
sum(OCT_QTY) as OCT_QTY,
sum(NOV_QTY) as NOV_QTY,
sum(DEC_QTY) as DEC_QTY,
sum(JAN_QTY) as JAN_QTY,
sum(FEB_QTY) as FEB_QTY
from LND_FPAR.Z_F_DDEPL_ALLRPTG a 
 join LND_FPAR.F_DDEPL_ALLRPTG b
  on a.YEAR_CD=b.YEAR_CD
and a.SCENARIO_CD= b.SCENARIO_CD
and a.MANAGEMENT_CD=b.MANAGEMENT_CD
and a.PRODUCT_CD=b.PRODUCT_CD
 and a.OPCO_CD=b.OPCO_CD
 and a.ACCOUNT_CD=b.ACCOUNT_CD
--where opco_cd='OCO101'
 group by  
YEAR_CD,
SCENARIO_CD,
MANAGEMENT_CD,
PRODUCT_CD,
OPCO_CD,
ACCOUNT_CD
order by year_cd;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a side-by-side comparison using `union all` and conditional aggregation:

```
select YEAR_CD, SCENARIO_CD, MANAGEMENT_CD, PRODUCT_CD, OPCO_CD, ACCOUNT_CD,
       sum(case when which = 'a' then MAR_QTY end) as MAR_QTY_a,
       sum(case when which = 'b' then MAR_QTY end) as MAR_QTY_b,
       . . .
from ((select 'a' as which, YEAR_CD, SCENARIO_CD, MANAGEMENT_CD, PRODUCT_CD, OPCO_CD, ACCOUNT_CD,
              MAR_QTY, . . .
       from LND_FPAR.Z_F_DDEPL_ALLRPTG
      ) union all
      (select 'b' as which, YEAR_CD, SCENARIO_CD, MANAGEMENT_CD, PRODUCT_CD, OPCO_CD, ACCOUNT_CD,
              MAR_QTY, . . .
       from LND_FPAR.F_DDEPL_ALLRPTG
      )
     ) ab
group by YEAR_CD, SCENARIO_CD, MANAGEMENT_CD, PRODUCT_CD, OPCO_CD, ACCOUNT_CD;
```

(Fill in the `. . .` with the columns you want to compare.)

I don't know how you want to do the comparison.

Comment: i was thinking to sum all the months columns of both the tables  when YEAR_CD, SCENARIO_CD, MANAGEMENT_CD, PRODUCT_CD, OPCO_CD, ACCOUNT_CD are '=' in both the tables , the above one might but iam little confused ,, correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: select YEAR_CD, SCENARIO_CD, ..
sum(case when which = 'a' then MAR_QTY end) as MAR_QTY_a,
sum(case when which = 'c' then MAY_QTY end) as MAY_QTY_c,
sum(case when which = 'd' then JUN_QTY end) as JUN_QTY_d,
....... till feb from ((select 'a' as which, YEAR_CD, SCENARIO_CD, MANAGEMENT_CD, PRODUCT_CD, OPCO_CD, ACCOUNT_CD,
 MAR_QTY,APR_QTY,MAY_QTY,JUN_QTY,....FEB_QTY
from LND_FPAR.Z_F_DDEPL_ALLRPTG ) union all
      (select 'b' as which, YEAR_CD, SCENARIO_CD, MANAGEMENT_CD,..MAR_QTY,APR_QTY,MAY_QTY,JUN_QTY,...FEB_QTY from LND_FPAR.F_DDEPL_ALLRPTG )) ab
group by YEAR_CD, SCENARIO_CD, ..

Comment: i guess its simple but iam making it complex, 2 tables with same columns need to sum the amount columns when the rest of the columns are on  equal to condition when join

Comment: may be i don't need a union bu some kind on join( may be a sub query join)

Comment: This solution would not seem to be what you were thinking.